# Por que é importante informar aos usuários a politica de cookies?

Tags: cookies

Venho navegando em vários sites que em seus cabeçalhos mostram mensagens como:

> Este site utiliza cookies para melhorar a sua navegação. Ao navegar no site estará a consentir a sua utilização.

Tudo bem que os cookies são armazenados na máquina do usuário, mas é realmente necessário esses avisos? Existe outro motivo por trás? Não achei quase nada relacionado na internet.

Comment: Isso é uma lei europeia, salvo engano.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assim como dito nos comentários isso é uma lei que envolve a União Européia. Não é necessária em outros localidades, mas em todos países que pertencem a UE, ou para usuários da União Européia que acessem seu site, é importante e necessário que você mostre o aviso do uso de cookies.

> Para que este site funcione corretamente, às vezes colocamos pequenos arquivos de dados chamados de cookies em seu dispositivo. A maioria dos grandes sites faz isso também.

A [Política de Cookies](https://europa.eu/european-union/abouteuropa/cookies) foi feita para aumentar o conhecimento dos usuários sobre como suas informações estão sendo armazenadas, geridas e usadas através do uso de cookies. Em vários casos também é necessário obter o consentimento do usuário, seja através de um botão ou *checkbox*.

Pode ver mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://europa.eu/european-union/abouteuropa/cookies) e [aqui também](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/6253244?hl=en) nesse artigo relacionado da Google. Pode ver como exemplo a página de políticas de cookies do [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/policies/cookies/) e da [Google](https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/cookies/).

Alguns trechos interessantes, traduzidos:

> O que são cookies?
>
> Um cookie é um pequeno arquivo de texto que um site armazena em seu computador ou dispositivo móvel quando você visita o site. Ele permite que o site lembre suas ações e preferências (como login, idioma, tamanho da fonte e outras preferências de exibição) durante um período de tempo, para que não seja necessário continuar a inseri-las sempre que retornar ao site ou navegue de uma página para outra.
>
> Como usamos cookies?
>   Algumas de nossas páginas usam cookies para lembrar:
>
> - Suas preferências de exibição, como configurações de cores de contraste ou tamanho de fonte
> - Se você já respondeu a um pop-up de pesquisa que lhe pergunta se o conteúdo foi útil ou não (então você não será solicitado novamente)
> - Se você concordou (ou não) com nosso uso de cookies neste site
> - Além disso, alguns vídeos incorporados em nossas páginas usam um cookie para reunir anonimamente estatísticas sobre como você chegou e quais vídeos você visitou.
>
> Os cookies também são armazenados pela Europa Analytics, o serviço corporativo que mede a eficácia e eficiência dos sites da Comissão Européia no EUROPA.
>
> Utilizamos outros cookies?
>
> - Algumas de nossas páginas ou subsites podem usar cookies adicionais ou diferentes dos descritos acima. Se assim for, os detalhes destes serão fornecidos em sua página de aviso de cookies específica. Você pode ser solicitado pelo seu acordo para armazenar esses cookies.

Comment: Muito bem explicado, realmente não sabia dessa lei.

Comment: Essa lei se estende para `LocalStorage` e `SessionStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

Para saber o porque desse tipo de aviso, você precisa entender o que os cookies são capazes de fazer.

Os cookies são um recurso dos navegadores web que armazenam pequenas informações no computador para que sites possam “lembrar” algumas informações, como logins, preferências e outros.

Porém, agências publicitárias e empresas utilizam para rastrear internautas afim de saber suas preferências, muitas vezes comerciais, o que levou muitos programas anti-spyware a eliminarem este  tipo de cookies.

De tempos em tempos você pode deletar os cookies, normal, o site vai recolocar novos, se você permitir, todas as vezes que você entrar nele, sem stress, faça faxinas periódicas mesmo.

Entretanto existe um mecanismo chamado “evercookie” no qual permite que um site armazene alguma informação no computador,permitindo que o usuário seja sempre rastreado.

São necessários seis passos para remover um evercookie do Firefox. No Chrome, são quatro. Para o Safari, no Mac, um código específico foi criado. O software de limpeza BleachBit é capaz de apagar os evercookies do Internet Explorer. Em alguns dispositivos, com o iPhone, apagar o evercookie é uma verdadeira guerra. 
Dos modos de navegação privada, apenas o do Safari impede completamente o evercookie.